# multiple delegates in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, protocols

i have been working on moving one of my apps away from the "shared appdelegate" process which seems to be frowned up, despite its over whelming use. i have been attempting to setup protocol methods for what i want to do but am having zero luck. my question is, can you even have lets say a single viewcontroller send delegate requests to multiple classes? from what im finding out it doesn't seem like you can. which doesn't make sense because i thought that was the whole point of delegates and protocols with mvc. now just to clarify, i know you can have a single viewcontroller act as the delegate for multiple other viewcontrollers. but that's not what i am asking. for a simple example, lets say you have apples flip-utility template. the "done" button just calls a delegate method to the mainvc to dismiss it. now lets say we added a new class called...

```
@interface NewClass : NSObject <TheOtherDelegate>
```

and it had a delegate method...

```
- (void)doSomething
{
NSLog(@"The Delegate did something...");
}
```

can we have a button on the flipsideviewcontroller, that we wanted to call that delegate method, but still keep the "done" button call to the delegate method on the mainviewcontroller that dismisses it?

that being said, i put together a quicky project just to see if it would work and it doesn't. i came across an "answer" that says you have to instantiate the class first you want to be the delegate...

```
NewClass *myDelegate = [NewClass alloc] init]
[fillInMethodHere setDelegate:myDelegate];
```

not sure why it got a correct answer check, because needless to say it doesn't work. is there something i am missing? i scoured ib to see if there is some "delegate" connection somewhere but i couldn't find anything.

on a side note, as i was working in my working project, i read a suggestion about removing the `#import` and adding `@class`. again, that broke all kinds of things. the strange thing is before doing that, what i had so far was working and building fine. when i removed the new `@class` and un-commented the `#import`. xcode all of a sudden gave me an error "cannot find protocol deceleration for..." but yet, it worked seconds earlier. i would up having to remove the protocol code and re-add it for it to work again. very starge.

any help would be appreciated. everything iv read in docs, google, stack, etc that say something should work, don't in an actual project.

Comment: Are you sure you imported both delegates using that < > thing?

Stanford made a demo that worked with 2 delegates. I can link you to it

Comment: You can't have multiple delegates because delegates make decisions for the delegator. What if multiple delegates were to disagree? I think you're conceiving of a delegate as a sort of observer, which is just informed about things, but that's wrong. The Observer pattern, implemented in Cocoa using `NSNotificationCenter` and friends, is different.

Comment: I'm sure that you CAN get multiple delegates. What you're saying is about having multiple delegates of the same kind. That's totally different from having multiple delegates as general

Comment: @ken that's pretty much my question is if it can even be done. and by no means am i conceiving delegates as an observer. just by pure definition alone, a delegate "does something for you". a delegate doesn't wait around just watching and doing nothing. ok, maybe in government they do. what i may be over thinking, is just simply sending a request to run a method in another class. i know everyone always says "rtfm", but the docs always say to use delegates and protocols for those types of tasks. as far as delegates "disagreeing", they shouldn't if following mvc.

Comment: @TheNavigator i have seen some of the stanford things. some are a bit hokey, because they use like tabbarcontrollers or tableviews that have their own canned delegates. unfortunately that doesn't help with a custom app that doesn't use any of those. but if you have something you think would be beneficial i would be more than happy to take a look. to your question about declaring delegates with the "< >" you might not be catching what i am saying. i have two separate classes i want to each act as a delegate for one class. so each .h file would only have one custom delegate declared.

Comment: It looks like I don't understand what you want to do here. Do you want 2 delegates that 1 object deals with (which is by declaring 2 delegates in the < > thing obviously), or 1 delegate which deals with 2 classes, or what?

Comment: @TheNavigator i think you might be confusing your nomenclatures. declaring in the "< >" means you conform to those delegate protocols, meaning you are the delegate. you are acting on behalf of another class. i want a single class that has two seperate delegate classes. visual would be like this (class a) --tell--> (class1)-{do_something_method} & (class a) --tell--> (class2)-{do_something_else_method}. basically i need a delegate for pushing/popping view controllers, then another for updating a model class. like this (vc2) --tell--> (vc1)-{remove_vc2} & (vc2) --tell--> (model)-{do_something}.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A "delegate" isn't some fancy object. It's simply a synthesized property of type id called `delegate`. If you wanted to, you could have an arbitrary number of properties that all conformed to the same protocol. Then when you wanted to issue a callback, you would just address all of them:

```
[self.mydelegateA doSomething];
[self.mydelegateB doSomething];
```

etc.

You could also have an `NSMutableArray` property that you could add objects to, and then use `[self.myMutableArrayOfDelegates makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(doSomething)]`.

Finally, there's always the route of `NSNotificationCenter` (not to be confused with push notifications) is a class that provides an inter-object messaging system. Many objects can register for a message that any other object can send.

Please see the Apple's documentation for more information. [Click Here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html)

Regardless of the fact that this is OS X documentation, it's still quite good at explaining things visually: [click here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)

Here's an example of simply changing the name of the delegate property: [click here](http://jackl.s3.amazonaws.com/Multi-Delegate%20Test%20-%20rename.zip)

And here's an example of adding another protocol and a second delegate: [click here](http://jackl.s3.amazonaws.com/Multi-Delegate%20Test%20-%20multi%20protocol.zip)

Finally, here's an example that builds on the previous two and has a third delegate that also conforms to the same protocol: [click here](http://jackl.s3.amazonaws.com/Multi-Delegate%20Test%20-%20round%203.zip)

Comment: As @JackLawrence says, just name them differently. Think of it like a UITableView.  It really has two delegates.  One called "delegate" and one called "dataSource".  They just had to name it something else because you can't have two variables called delegate (and even if you could, you couldn't organize your delegate calls very well that way!).

Comment: @inafziger exactly! I meant to put in that little tidbit about `UITableView` but totally forgot.

Comment: @jack the problem is your [self.delegateA doSomething],etc. doesn't work. if you read my question thoroughly you'll see i did that and it doesn't work. you can't even take a working delegate and change all the property and sythesize declarations from "delegate" to "adelegate". if you dont believe me, create a new "utility" template app and change "<FlipsideViewController>delegate" in the .h & "@synthesize delegate = _delegate" in the .m to something else and see what happens. spoiler alert, the app will crash. again, canned apple delegates protocols may work fine, but custom ones dont seem to.

Comment: @DoS I've edited my post and added links to sample projects I created using the Utility template for iPhone. As a side note, unless a property has the keyword IBOutlet before it or a method has the keyword IBAction as the return type, you don't need to check interface builder for any potential connection issues.

Comment: @jack great! i look forward to checking all that out. its people like you who take the time to post such thorough answers that help create better developers.

Comment: @JackLawrence i just went through all the links you sent and the xcode projects. my question for you is, i created a sample app that's nearly identical to your examples. the one major difference was i opted to let the template use storyboards. for some reason making the same changes you did, it did break the app like i mentioned. thanks again for the information. i can't say how priceless it is seeing working real world examples. the only real way to learn how something works is to take it apart, the reassemble  it and see if it still works.

Comment: Wait a second, it's still not working? *mind blown*. Okay. I'm going to try a storyboard project, with arc enabled, and get back to you.

Comment: @DoS what's the exception it throws when you crash? The StoryBoard version is almost identical except you set the properties in performSegue.

Comment: @JackLawrence just for clarification, your samples work perfectly. but i think the problem with storyboards is the "prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender" method. it doesn't allocate a vc from nib like your way. and if alloc the flipvc manual it doesn't work either. also the "[[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self]" call i think limits setting the delegate to just one. even if i change that to self.otherDelegateName it doesn't work. it doesn't crash the app unless i try and use the "done" button. the "delegate button" yields no results.

Comment: There's no conceptual difference between storyboards and non-storyboard protocol implementations. I just whipped one up in Xcode using the same methodology. Protocols are hard to use/implement unless you understand how they work and what they're for, as well as how properties and methods work. I can assure you that it works in all cases. Case and point is UITableView. They're not doing anything different from you and I - you can check the header files and see for yourself.

Comment: @JackLawrence i do understand the concept of delegates. and i can implement them, but i promise there is something not quite the same with storyboards. when i put a breakpoint on the flipside buttons. i can see the _delegate is in fact being instantiated, but _otherDelegate is not "_otherDelegate objc_object * 0x00000000". i truly believe this has something to do with the storyboard segue process. if i add the "flipsideFinished" method in my other class, and set self.otherDelegate, that method gets called but "_delegate" is whats being allocated. which it should be both. try & see for yourself

Comment: I did try. You're probably not retaining the object _otherDelegate points to by setting it to a strongly typed property. Or you're not initializing it.

Comment: @JackLawrence i appricate your time and help, but i don't want to saturate the post with our back & forth. plus i would like to send you my sample code so you can see for yourself whats happening. is there any way we can touch base off stack without reveling any private or personal info?

Comment: @JackLawrence hahaha! its funny you say that, i just thought the same thing, and changed from weak to (strong, nonatomic) but its the same results.